# Get name of outer function from inner function object in python

Tags: python

Assume a nested function in python, where `outer` denotes the outer function and `inner` denotes the inner function. The outer function provides parametrization of the inner function and returns an instance of this parametrized function.

I want to obtain the name of the outer function, given an instance of the inner function which is returned by the outer function.
The code is as follows:

```
def outer(a):
    def inner(x):
        return x*a
    return inner
p = outer(3)
print p  # prints inner
print p(3)  # prints 9
```

How can I print the name of the outer function, ie `outer`, given only `p`?
Thanks!

Comment: You cannot. `print p` only prints 'inner' because 'outer' returns a function that happens to be 'inner'

Comment: Actually this is not a bad question, if you are looking for *why* you cannot do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
from functools import wraps

def outer(a):
    @wraps(outer)
    def inner(x):
        return x*a
    return inner
p = outer(3)
print p  # <function outer at ...>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like an elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means an elegant solution, and I personally wouldn't use it. However it answers the question that you asked.

```
def outer(a):
    def inner(x):
        return x*a
    inner.__name__ = 'outer'
return inner

print p
<function outer at 0x10eef8e60>
```